# Set required form fields using FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am building an application in FastAPI and need to receive form fields (x-www-form-urlencoded). I used [this page](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) to figure out what to do, And I found I had to use the class: `Form(...)`. The problem is that I want to set the fields as required (to appear in the documentation as required, and also that if they are missing the app will return 422). `Form` has one required argument, which is: `default`, but once the `default` is set the field is no required. I tried to write: `Form(None)`, but it did not help. Is there a way to solve the problem?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your view function signature look like? `Form(...)` as shown in the example should work (with the three dots).

Comment: It seems unexpected to me to incorporate three dots within the Python code, so I thought they mean is to put there an arguments. I tried and it did work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any parameter defined as `Form(...)` (including the three dots) in your view signature will be required by default. Make sure that you actually include the three dots - they do have a purpose.